# Raytracing not responding correctly

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, raycasting, unity3d-2dtools

So I'm new to Unity and I'm sure I'm missing an easy step, but after looking online for a while for some reason I can't find the solution.

I have two objects on the screen, player and enemy. Both have Rigidbody2D, and Box Collider 2D attached. On Box Collider 2D I have clicked `is triggered` On Rigidbody2D for both I have clicked `Is Kinematic`. On player I have a simple movement script. On the enemy object I have this:

```
void Update () {
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.localPosition,transform.right,Mathf.Infinity);
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.localPosition,transform.right);
    if (hit)
      Debug.Log(hit.collider);
}
```

Now for some reason when I move player over the object `if (hit)`
 is true, but if I move the player anywhere on the right side it is not true. What would be the reason for this? Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing the reason for this behavior is because you are only doing a raycast to the right and when you go pass the object on the right then there is nothing for the raycast to hit.

Comment: I must not understand the principal of raycasting, what I think this code should be doing is sending out a ray to the right side of its origin, and then if anything collides with that ray, hit becomes true. Is that not what this is doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you don't need Rigidbody for raycast detection, only colliders. Second, Physics2D.Raycast uses world position, not local, so replace "transform.localPosition" with "transform.position", this messes it up a lot if the transform is child of something. Take in mind that you are sending raycast from the right side of your transform, so maybe it's not hitting anything and values you are getting are actually correct.

Comment: Hey, so I changed it transform.position, but it's still not reading when I have another object pass it on the right side. Is there anything additionally I need to do? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Solved it by tinkering around with the if statement. Thanks.